# Unable to add odbc5.jar in classpath

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to connect to the oracle DB using Play Framework 1.2.5. FOr this I have modified the `application.conf` file as follows:

```
 db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
 db.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
 db.user=system
 db.pass=tiger
```

Then I tried to add the driver i.e. `classes12.jar`/`odbc5.jar` but everytime when i try to run it, I am getting the exception:

`Cannot connect to the database, Driver not found`

For adding the jar file in Eclipse IDE, below are the steps I tried:

1) Added it in the lib folder (present under the root directory of my new application) and then added it to the `java build path`

2) Added it in the framework/lib folder (inside the downloaded framework folder) and then added it to the `java build path`

In both the cases, I am getting the above mentioned exception.

Also, Please list down the steps for connection to an oracle db, I am not able to find it anywhere in the documentation

**EDIT**

I am able to add the jar in the classpath, everything was fine except that I did not restarted the server once it failed to connect the jar.

I did this code for fetching some data from the database:

```
Connection conn = DB.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement  stmt = null;
    System.out.println(conn);
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select dept_id from emp where emp_id = 11");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Dept Id: " + rs.getInt("dept_id"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This approach is working but I am having a confusion:

If I comment the entire block of code and run the application then I can see the message  in the console stating the connection is made to the DB. Hence :

1) Is the above block of code the right approach to fetch the data from Oracle DB or something better than this is present?

2) Is it like for the entire application lifetime, the connection with tht DB will persist?

I am a newbie in this, hence struggling :(

Please let me know hoe to proceed with this.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle db driver class name is `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Comment: I have edited my above post...can you please suggest something?

Comment: Rather than editing the existing post to add another question, I'd post another question...